# Plugin parecido com quiz

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Alguém conhece algum plugin que faça função "parecida" com QUIZ, aonde o cliente vai respondendo questionário, no final ele preenche um formulário com dados dele(que eu recuperaria depois pra poder entrar em contato), mas no meu caso preciso pra orçamento, algo parecido com esse site: http://www.quarteldesign.com/orcamento-online/

Comment: Já testou com o Google Forms? https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wpgform/#description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi vc precisa de algo chamado **Multi Step Form** ou **Form Wizard** nesse tipo de Form as campos de preenchimento vão aparecendo por etapas.

Aqui tem algumas opões de *plugins* do WordPress. Mas no Google vc encontra outros facilmente.

---

**Multi Step Form**: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-step-form/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms: https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/
**Demo:** https://webheadcoder.com/contact-form-7-multi-step-form/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Pesquise por **Multi Step Form** ou **Form Wizard**
>
> *Mais opções direto no site Oficial **WordPress**:* https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/search/Multi+Step+Form/